# Python (with Tweetpy) going trough tweet archive and performing actions with each

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I want to go trough all tweets in .csv tweet archive downloaded from twitter, and perform actions with each, but I get errors like:

> File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tweetp\tweetp.py", line 39, in 
>       next(reader, None)
>
> File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1257.py", line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 782: character maps to < undefined >

And I struggle figuring it out. What makes it unable to read the .csv files and how do I make it work?
Here's the fragment of code where things fall apart:

```
with open(tweets_csv, 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)

  # Skip header
  next(reader, None)

  # Convert CSV to list
  tweets_list = list(reader)

for tweet in tweets_list:
    # tweet[0] is the tweet_id column
    tweet_id = tweet[0]
    print('[ - ] tweet with id %s' %(tweet_id))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try entering `encoding='utf-8'` parameter into the `open`function. If it still doesn't work, make sure you know first the file encoding. Use a text-editor that can detect and show the encoding or use `chardet` third-party Python module to detect it.

Comment: You may want to consider using pandas.read_csv https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv). This will read your CSV file into a dataframe.

Pass squeeze in the parameters - true and only one column is passed. 
Here is a nice [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-read-csv-using-pandas-read_csv/)

```
# Import pandas 
import pandas as pd

# make the passed column as index instead of 0, 1, 2, 3....
# below will print the values under the header 'tweets_column_title'
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_tweets_csv_file.csv', index_col = 'tweets_column_title', squeeze=True)

for i in df.iterrows(): 
    print(i[0])         # You can then simply extract each message like this.
```

Comment: @Eugenijus Krenis - If you could kindly up-vote my answer if you are satisfied with my answer. Thank you.